# Python bad file descriptor ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, encryption

I'm busting my head for a few days. I'm trying to make a connection between few clients through a server with sockets that are ssl wrapped. I followed the [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) to try and establish a secure connection. I start the server and after it the client. The connection "seems" to go through, but it really doesn't. As soon as I enter the username in the client and send a message, server breaks and outputs this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 52, in <module>
    t = Thread(target=deal_with_client(connstream))
  File "server.py", line 44, in deal_with_client
    newsocket.send(data.encode())       
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

This is the server.py file:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import ssl

# server's IP address
SERVER_HOST = "somehostname"
SERVER_PORT = 5007 # port we want to use
separator_token = "<SEP>" # we will use this to separate the client name & message
newsockets = set()
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="certificate.crt", keyfile="private.pem")

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
bindsocket.listen(5)


def deal_with_client(connstream):
    while True:
        try:
            data = connstream.recv(1024).decode()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")

            newsockets.remove(connstream)
        else:
            data = data.replace(separator_token, "-> ")
        for newsocket in newsockets:
            newsocket.send(data.encode())       


while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    newsockets.add(newsocket)
    print(f"[+] {fromaddr} connected.")
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    t = Thread(target=deal_with_client(connstream))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

And this is the client.py file:

```
import socket
import random
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import Fore, init, Back
import ssl 

# init colors
init()

# prompt the client for a name
name = input("Enter your name: ")

# set the available colors
colors = [Fore.BLUE, Fore.CYAN, Fore.GREEN, Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX, Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX, Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.RED, Fore.WHITE, Fore.YELLOW
]

# choose a random color for the client
client_color = random.choice(colors)

# server's IP address
# if the server is not on this machine, 
# put the private (network) IP address (e.g 192.168.1.2)
SERVER_HOST = "somehostname"
SERVER_PORT = 5007 
separator_token = "<SEP>" 



context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)

context.load_verify_locations('certificate.crt')

conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname="somehostname")
conn.connect(("somehostname", SERVER_PORT))
   
print(f"[*] Connecting to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")
print("[+] Connected.")


def listen_for_messages():
    while True:
        message = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        print("\n" + message)

t = Thread(target=listen_for_messages)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    to_send =  input()
    if to_send.lower() == 'q':
        break
    date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    to_send = f"{client_color}[{date_now}] {name}{separator_token}{to_send}{Fore.RESET}"
    conn.send(to_send.encode())
```

I tried encoding, and decoding messages. I tried addid 'utf-8'... Nothing seems to work. Anyone have an idea where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Why do you send the reply to all sockets and not just the client? See in https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html how the server deals only with the `connstream` of the client, and not all sockets. Also you may want to first try a simple case without threading, and then see with threading.

Comment: You add `newsocket` (unwrapped) to the set but then try to remove `connstream` (wrapped). This should fail. Similar the `send` might give a problem since you try to use the unwrapped socket with established TLS. I recommend that you name your variables more clear so that you always know when you are dealing with wrapped and unwrapped sockets.

Comment: Also, since `deal_with_client()` is trying to broadcast to all established clients, you need to provide thread synchronization around updates to `newsockets`, as well as around `send()` of each socket in `newsockets`. The way your code is written, you can easily end up in situations where `newsockets` is bring modified while other threads are looping through it, and where multiple threads try to `send()` to the same client at the same time corrupting communications with that client due to overlapping messages.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I want to create a chat for multiple clients.That's why I want to send the reply to everyone.

I made this work without SSL, now I'm losing my mind over it. Thanks guys.